# How to set Dependency Properties in a Control which inherits from an abstract UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, dependency-properties, relativesource

I've got a Control (mySubControl) which inherits from a UserControl (myAbstractControl) which is abstract.
When I try to set dependency Properties inside mySubControl I always get errors on runtime, saying:

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'myPropertyRegistrationName' property not found on ...."

I think somehow the DataContext of mySubControl gets messed up.

I tried to use the relative bindings, but it also doesn't fix it.

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type myNS:myType}},
                     Path=myPropertyRegistrationName}"
```

Can anybody help me ?

Thx

Comment: The part with the `not found on` is kind of important, the `...` doesn't help. If the `DataContext` is not what you want that part would tell you.

Comment: What is `myNS:myType`? Also considering you are binding to a `Type` instance, your property `myPropertyRegistrationName` **should be** declared static and also should be of type `Visibility` as I dont see any converters in the binding either.

Comment: Please update your post with the actula DP declaration. Make sure you use the right name (i.e. the first argument in your DP declaratio), not the actual CLR name of the DP property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always syntax, isn't it ?

```
Visibility="{Binding myPropertyRegistrationName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=myNS:myType}}"
```

Thx anyway.